# Django-CMS plugin not appearing

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm deploying a Django website. All the custom plugins I have work on my computer (I can add them into a template block from the drop down.) but when I push the code out to the site, not all the plugins are available.

The database tables are created, and if I import `plugin_pool` and call `discover_plugins()` and then `get_all_plugins()` the plugins all show up. So my question is, why aren't my plugins showing? Any ideas?

Comment: Might you suggest some? I really don't know where to begin looking django-cms for this.

Answer (score 4):

Is your app with the plugin (`cms_plugins.py` file) in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Does it have a `models.py` (which could be empty) file?

Can you import the `cms_plugins.py` file when using `python manage.py shell`?

The most common problem are import errors in the cms_plugins.py file

Comment: yes, yes, and yes :( I've given up and just worked around the problem.

Comment: Make sure you can import `cms_plugins.py` from shell. Note, INSTALLED_APPS list will only check for models, not cms_plugins, so the server load even with an error in `cms_plugins.py`. When CMS Plugins List tries to import `cms_plugins.py`, and there's an error, it won't alert or log this, it will simply ignore. So, break out the shell and figure out where the error is. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this issue while following the [basic example](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extending_cms/custom_plugins.html) for Django CMS 3. The example suggests that the following code will work (with the associated template in place):

```
#cms_plugins.py
from cms.models.pluginmodel import CMSPlugin
class HelloPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = CMSPlugin
    render_template = "hello_plugin.html"

plugin_pool.register_plugin(HelloPlugin)
```

However, I found that when using `CMSPlugin` as the model the plugin is not visible in the page structure editor.

This is despite the fact that the Plugin is:

1. In the root directory of an app that is listed in the project's `INSTALLED APPS`
2. The app had a `models.py` file (but the plugin was not using any of those models)
3. The `cms_plugins.py` file could be imported from a django shell

Try the django shell import, as listed on the example page:

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> from django.utils.importlib import import_module 
>>> m = import_module("myapp.cms_plugins")
```

The solution was to use a model defined in the `models.py` file, which extends CMSPlugin:

```
#cms_plugins.py
from .models import MyModel

class HelloPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = MyModel
    render_template = "hello_plugin.html"

plugin_pool.register_plugin(HelloPlugin)

# models.py
class MyModel(CMSPlugin):
    pass
```

Like magic, the plugin was then listed under 'Generic' on the page structure editor.