# djangocms-cascade not in plugin dropdown?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I'm trying to get djangocms-cascade 0.4.0 to work (0.3.2 seems to work fine), but there is no option for it in the dropdown on the edit page of django cms.

I am pretty sure I have it, at least mostly, correctly installed since I can import it via the shell (as recommended by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770844/django-cms-plugin-not-appearing).)

## My Settings.py

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    # Theme
    'bootstrap3',

    # Django CMS
    'cmsplugin_cascade',
    'cms',
    'mptt',
    'menus',
    'sekizai',
    'djangocms_admin_style',
    'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',

    'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
    'cms.context_processors.cms_settings',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)

# Static Files

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'cms': 'cms.migrations_django',
    'menus': 'menus.migrations_django',
}

# Django CMS
# http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/basic_reference/configuration.html

CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ('cms_default.html', 'Default'),
)

CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {
    'Page Content': {
        'plugins': ['BootstrapContainerPlugin'],
    },
}

# Django CMS Cascade
# http://djangocms-cascade.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#configure-the-css-framwork

CMS_CASCADE_PLUGINS = ('bootstrap3',)
```

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at the 0.4.0 related installation documentation  https://github.com/jrief/djangocms-cascade/blob/0.4.0/docs/source/installation.rst

It says

> To activate all available Bootstrap plugins, use:
>
> CMS_CASCADE_PLUGINS = ('cmsplugin_cascade.bootstrap3',)